# Cubic runout spline (cubic spline)

Tags: interpolation, spline

I was studying cubic spline interpolation and then I stumbled upon "Cubic runout spline". The idea behind it is that you set the boundary conditions for second derivatives to be:

$f_1''(x_0) = 2f_1''(x_1) - f_2''(x_2)$

$f_n''(x_n) = 2f_n''(x_{n-1}) - f_{n-1}''(x_{n-2})$

As a result, the first two and last two points have their own single curve.

Now, I've figured out the natural, clamped, periodic, not-a-knot type splines and their ideas and proofs, but this one for some reason confused me.

---

I want to try prove that $M_0 = 2M_1 - M_2$ <=> first 2 curves are the same.
I wrote a system of equations for $M_0, M_1$ and $M_2$, where $M_i$ - is a second derivative of our function at point i. I ended up with this:

$S_i(x) = \alpha_i + \beta_i (x - x_i) + \gamma_i (x - x_i)^2 + \delta_i (x - x_i)^3$

$M_0 = 2 \gamma_0$

$M_1 = 2 \gamma_1 = 2 \gamma_0 + 6\delta_0 h_1$

$M_2 = 2 \gamma_1 + 6 \delta_1 h_2$

$h$ is the difference between adjacent x-values

Now, I decided to split the solution into 2 parts: first one is where $h_1 = h_2 = h$ and the second is where they are different.

1. for the first part: solving this from right to left (i.e. same curves => equation holds) yielded $\delta_0 = \delta_1 = 0$, which then gave me $M_0 = M_1 = M_2$, which gives me the final equation. Now, the opposite (left to right) proof kinda stopped me. I managed to derive the equality of delta but for gamma I failed to proceed further.

Could anyone give me a hint regarding the proper approach towards this?

Comment: One approach you might want to try to prove that the first two curves are the same is to check if the left and right *third* (why?) derivatives at the second point are the same. (The procedure is analogous for the last two curves and the penultimate point.) For inspiration, you might want to see [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137658).