# Does not-a-knot cubic spline interpolation always have a tridiagonal system of equations when solving for the second derivatives?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spline

I've been looking at the question [Not-a-knot cubic spline interpolation using tridiagonal solver](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135857/not-a-knot-cubic-spline-interpolation-using-tridiagonal-solver), for much the same reasons as the original asker - to figure out how to implement not-a-knot spline interpolation using a tridiagonal solver.

The definitions from that answer/question are as follows:
$$i=0,1,...,n-2,n-1$$
$$h_i = x_{i+1} - x_i$$
$$\delta_i=\dfrac{y_{i+1}^{\prime\prime}-y_i^{\prime\prime}}{6h_i}$$
$$s_i=\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i}$$

While the answer is very helpful and makes a lot of sense, I'm running into an issue when the answerer solved for the second derivatives instead of the first, which uses the equation: 
$$S_i(x)=y_i+\beta_i\left(x-x_i\right)+\frac{y_i^{\prime\prime}}{2}\left(x-x_i\right)^2+\delta_i\left(x-x_i\right)^3$$
As they proved in their answer, by combining
$$h_0 y_0^{\prime\prime}+2(h_0+h_1)y_1^{\prime\prime}+h_1 y_2^{\prime\prime}=6(s_1-s_0)$$
with the not-a-knot boundary conditions, you get the following equation: $$(h_0^2-h_1^2)y_0^{\prime\prime}+(2h_0^2+3h_0 h_1+h_1^2)y_1^{\prime\prime}=6h_0(s_1-s_0)$$
However, in the case that the first three points are equally spaced, or that $h_0 = h_1$,
then the equation resolves to 
$$hy_1'' = (s_1 - s_0)$$ 
where $h=h_0=h_1$.
It's possible to get a second equation by substituting the value of $y_1''$ into one of the earlier equations: 
$$hy_0''+hy_2'' = 4(s_1-s_0)$$

While I think these equations would fully define the system, they aren't tridiagonal, correct? Is there a tridiagonal solution when solving for the second derivatives, under the circumstances $h_0=h_1$ (or $h_{n-2}=h_{n-1}$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the system is still tridiagonal. It is perfectly possible for a tridiagonal system to have zeroes in its diagonal or off-diagonal elements, e.g.

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&2&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

would still be considered a tridiagonal matrix. Precisely this kind of situation will arise if your abscissas are equispaced in your cubic spline.